# getting error while using JAW

Tags: wordnet, jvm-arguments

hi I am a JAW beginner. 
I followed the steps given by a site for using JAW. but getting following error. It would be a great help if some one tell me what will be the directory path for VM argument.. for more specification my WordNet dictionary is in C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\Dict (dictionary location)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Files\WordNet\2/1\dict\
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\WordNet\2.1\dict\
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 Could not find the main class: Files\WordNet\2.1\dict\.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the dot in your folder name 2.1

Rename your folder to something else than 2/1 or 2.1
compare the paths in your two top lines.
GL!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have got solution to the the same problem. I have renamed the directory. Normally Directory should not contain any special characters like '(' or '.' etc..